# Can I make a custom waiter that waits with epoll_wait but also immediately returns if a condition variable changes?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, posix, epoll

I'm working on a socket library that uses a loop that uses epoll_wait to wait for all sockets, like this:

```
int ret = epoll_wait(_epoll_fd, events, EPOLL_SIZE, minDelay ? minDelay : -1);
```

I want to also wait for a virtual socket. That is, suppose that I have a totally virtual socket, which is simply a class that randomly generates some data every now and then to simulate a socket. There are no file descriptors.

How can I integrate this virtual socket in to the library's poller?

Is there something that can immediately return if any of the file descriptors is read or written but **also** return immediately if something changes on my virtual socket? (perhaps waiting for a condition variable)

Comment: `epoll_wait` can only wait on file descriptors. That's it. Your "virtual socket" needs to abstract itself behind a file descriptor of some sort. A pipe, maybe, so that it can be treated like a file descriptor, and join epoll_wait's big happy family.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `pipe` as a unidirectional or `socketpair` as a bidirectional channel to transfer data. If you just want to signal an event, take a look at `eventfd`.